# How to change custom taxonomy terms order per post in Wordpress without plugin

Tags: wordpress, custom-taxonomy

I have to order my custom taxonomy terms per post. So, I have to change order of taxonomy terms that related custom post type posts while post displaying.

I have a custom post type that called "article" and I have a custom taxonomy that called "article-author". So an "article" can have more than one "article-authors". No problem so far.

But when display an article, related article-authors order by name. But I have to sort article-authors by custom order and I have to define it's order before the article saved (if possible... or not, can change it after saved).

Comment: What is the custom order you want?

Comment: I think my question is not clear enough :) So, in short I want to change post terms order per post based on the post add/edit screen.

Comment: So you are looking to change the order of the listed authors, on a per article basis?